# git add -i keeps returning perl no user error on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: perl, git, osx-lion

`git add -i` is giving me the following error

> perl: no user 502

It has always worked fine but now, out of the blue, I am getting this error. All other commands like `git add <filename>`, `git status`, `git commit` are working fine.

What's going on here?

This is the output of command `id`

> >
>   $ id
>
> uid=502(andy) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),402(com.apple.access_ssh),403(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2),401(com.apple.access_screensharing),12(everyone),33(_appstore),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer)

Comment: Please provide output of command `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple restart fixed the issue.

Comment: If this was on a mac, you should mention that in your question so that other people with a similar problem can find the solution easily.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://community.zenoss.org/thread/15807 it is issue with Apple's perl. It it hard to tell, whether presented solution applies to your case as well, but please consider giving it a try.